# Running an application within an application in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a main project, a large web site, within Visual Studio 2013. It is a site that we are slowly migrating piecemeal into .NET. The main project consists of several sections and has its own web.config. Let's say, for example purposes, that the site is **www.example.com**.

Under **www.example.com**, we have a plethora of subfolders. Some of these subfolders I am simply just running off the root application and root web.config, so no individual application is needed, but I am now beginning to come across some folders that once were independent .NET applications with their own web.config files and their own application instances in IIS. Let's say one of the application subfolders is **www.example.com/app1/**. When I move **/app1/** into my project, however, the master pages and placeholder references are out of sync due to the use of "~/" in the file structure definitions and simply because these folders were once individual applications.

My question is this, is it possible to build and deploy these subfolders as their own applications within the main application while maintaining their "~/" .NET link structure? Furthermore, if it is possible, is that a good practice to maintain multiple applications within one main application project? I figure I am not the only person to need or request something like this. Or should I just add these subfolders to the main project as individual projects and build them in a dependency order?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, for tiddyness I would have a Solution with multiple web projects, each for each web application you have in the IIS. Remember that since you have folders configured in the server, you don't need to have the same enviroment in you development enviroment. So, You can have these structure in the VS Solution:

```
\My Solution
-- \ Web App 1 (Root)
-- \ Web App 2 (Subfolder 1 in Root)
-- \ Web App 3 (Subfolder 2 in Root)
-- \ Web App 4 (Subfolder 3 in Root)
```

You only have to take caution on deploying each web App to the correct folder in the server. Folder that has to be configured as an Application in IIS for the especific web.config file.

Comment: So is this considered a best practice? We have our dev-test-prod environments all matching so although I don't necessarily need to have a similar environment, it sometimes makes more sense to if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it as a best practice, since having Applications inside Appplications isn't a good practice for me, as I don't find it as a normal approach. But since you have it that way, I propose how you could cope with it to make your life easier.
Another solution, could be the "merge" of all web.config files, and the fixing of the "~\" for the correct folders, and ending the Applications inside Applications. But notice that you can have a Application folder inside an Application/site, that in the file system, isn't really inside the main/root folder.

Comment: You can, and I think in this case you should, to split the logic of the Application and Sub-Applications, because above all, they are all independent application. If they aren't why are configured like that?